# Problem with the integration function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Please tell me why Wolfram Mathematica calculates the integral incorrectly? She simply replaces s with Rho and subtracts the lower limit from the upper limit. I did the same as indicated in the documentation.

```
SigmaPhiEnd[Rho_] = 1
SigmaPhiBegin[Rho_] = SigmaPhiEnd[Rho] + (Kappa Rho^2 - a^2)/((Kappa Rho^2 + a^2) Rho) Integrate[SigmaPhiEnd[s], {s, Rho, BEnd}]
SigmaPhi[Rho_, t_] = SigmaPhiBegin[Rho] + Integrate[SigmaPhiBegin[s] (s (a^2 - Kappa Rho^2))/(Rho^2 (a^2 + Kappa s^2)), {s, Rho, BEnd}]
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Can you please be a bit more specific? You have two integrals there. Which one is supposed to be incorrect, and what is your expected result?

Comment: @Domen, Inside the first integral there is 1, so it is considered true. In the second integral, as I wrote above, instead of the operation of integration over the variable s, the variable s is replaced by the variable Rho. And further multiplication by the difference between the upper and lower limits. I don't know what to add since I wrote everything in the question above. Now I wrote essentially the same thing. Added a photo to the question.

Comment: Many syntactic errors, e.g., omission of semicolons in separate functions, mi-use of = (immediate assignment), and more.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what is going on in the code you posted.  I find it much easier to debug things if you put one command per cell.

```
SigmaPhiEnd[Rho_] = 1 (*this evaluates to 1 no matter what*)
```

so this is equivalent (notice the lower case):

```
sigmaPhiEnd = 1;
```

And so your:

```
SigmaPhiBegin[Rho_] =  SigmaPhiEnd[Rho] +
 (Kappa Rho^2 - a^2)/((Kappa Rho^2 + a^2) Rho)
 Integrate[SigmaPhiEnd[s], {s, Rho, BEnd}] (*SigmaPhiEnd[Rho] is always 1*)
```

is equivalent to:

```
sigmaPhiBegin = 
 sigmaPhiEnd + (Kappa Rho^2 - a^2)/((Kappa Rho^2 + a^2) Rho)
 Integrate[sigmaPhiEnd, {s, Rho, BEnd}]
```

which is equivalent to:

```
sigmaPhiBegin = 
     1 + (Kappa Rho^2 - a^2)/((Kappa Rho^2 + a^2) Rho)
     Integrate[1, {s, Rho, BEnd}]
```

Finally

```
sigmaPhiBegin + 
 Integrate[
  sigmaPhiBegin (s (a^2 - Kappa Rho^2))/(Rho^2 (a^2 + Kappa s^2)), {s, Rho, 
   BEnd}]
```

integrates with conditions which is what you have.

While it is fine to introduce functions as you did, you didn't need to as you can see.

If you do use functions with patterns, you (*almost*) always want to use `:=`

Comment: I've made some progress on my solution. Please tell me which function in Wolfram Mathematics should be used to divide element by element by Rho^2? I need this to make a replacement for Rho/a in the future.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Does (a + b + c)/Rho^2 divide everything by Rho^2 the way you want?   Perhaps you want to introduce a scaled dimensionless variable for a length? Then use a pattern-replace: (expression with Rho)/.Rho-> a nondimR

Comment: Did my answer above not answer your original question?

Comment: "Perhaps you want to introduce a scaled dimensionless variable for a length?", yes.

Comment: How to do this programmatically?

Comment: Something like:  `(Rho^2 - b +  b Rho)/.Rho->a r` where r is now non-dimensional.

Comment: Please tell me how to display these functions on a graph now? My attempt to do this is at the link: https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/a7e28946-0cde-438a-97c7-8541f0e00024

Comment: @Maks - do not ask new questions ("how to plot") in comments of questions ("how to integrate"). Post a new question and include all relevant code (copy and paste-able `InputForm`) in the question.